# Passing custom object at submit

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application. I mostly work on Spring, so don't know much about android development, so I have installed android annotations and Spring Rest template to connect to server to send data. 
Currently what I am trying to do, to fill in some text fields in the android app, the variables are mentioned in one Java file. Then at click of a button, I want to pass that object to one of the methods, where I can make a REST connection to the server to send the data. Kindly have a look at the code, and please let me know :

MyActivity :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    // At button push, this method is called, I checked that, but I would like to receive an Object of class mentioned below. 
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Log.d(view.toString(),"We reached sendMessage");
    }
}
```

Restaurant class :

```
public class Restaurant {

    private int id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String firstName;
//Getters and setters ommitted
}
```

layout file main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:weightSum="1" android:gravity="center"
              android:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="193dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:textStyle="italic" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:textSize="30dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Bitte geben Sie Ihre Daten ein"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:autoText="false" android:hint="Restaurant Name"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText4" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Restaurant Email" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText5" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:hint="Password"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:editable="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:hint="Street name, number" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText6" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:hint="Phone number"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/PLZ" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Standort ermitteln"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If anyone has user Spring-rest-template and Android annotations, a detailed tutorial then the small examples would be really helpful too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: check this library http://square.github.io/okhttp/ it will help you to make a RestCall to your server.

Comment: @Muthu I believe and saw some basic examples of android annotations where they do this and more. Do you know how receive the object at push of button as mentioned above?

Comment: You mean JsonObject?

Comment: It is a normal java object. Once I have that object in the sendMessage() method, I will send it via REST to server. My point is to use the text fields as variables from the Restaurant class, when the user types in details, an object is created at send button of type Restaurant for further processing.

Comment: Up to my Knowledge you can't send Java object as it is! You can send them as jsonObject string.

Comment: @Muthu So, it means, I cannot use some Java class, implement serializable and send over the java object to another activity or method in same activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71165/discussion-between-muthu-and-we-are-borg).

Comment: @Muthu Sorry man, had gone to lunch. Can you come now. I will wait. Thanks.

Comment: No probs lets continue in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.Id.restaurantName); 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    // At button push, this method is called, I checked that, but I would like to receive an Object of class mentioned below. 
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Log.d(view.toString(),editText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```